# Open Gmail from Android application

Tags: android, gmail

I'm trying to create an application that symply open Gmail. I use two function: startApplication and launchApp:

```
public void startApplication(String packageName){
            try
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

                for(ResolveInfo info : resolveInfoList)
                    if(info.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(packageName))
                    {
                        toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gmail opened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                        launchApp(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
                        return;
                    }
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can't find Gmail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
```

This is launchApp function:

```
private void launchApp(String packageName, String name)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, name));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I call from my onCreate function of MainActivity

> startApplication("com.gmail");

I try to run this application on emulator and smartphone, but the program crash. What is the error?

Comment: _Are you asking us to tell the error_.? You have the logcat, why dont you tell us the error.

Comment: My logcat is at http://pastebin.com/cJutP0HJ

Comment: The logcat says the error is on the line 15 of the com.polito.gmail.MainActivity . Please post your complete code and mention which is the line number 15.

Comment: Oh, at line 15 I made a big mistake. I correct it and the application don't crash, but it freezes without errors after launch.
The complete code is at http://pastebin.com/KEcYkit6

Comment: Finally I resolved changing startApplication("com.gmail") with startApplication("com.google.android.gm")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved changing `startApplication("com.gmail")` with `startApplication("com.google.android.gm")`